# Boost awaitable: write into a socket and await particular response

Tags: c++, boost-asio, c++20, asio, c++-coroutine

The problem can be a bit complex. I will try to explain the best possible the situation and what tools I imagined to solve my problems.

I am writing a socket application that may write into a socket and expects a response. The protocol enable that in an easy way: each request has a "command id" that will be forwarded back into the response so we can have code that react to that particular request.

For simplicity, we will assume all communication is done using json in the socket.

First, let's assume this session type:

```
using json = /* assume any json lib */;

struct socket_session {
    auto write(json data) -> boost::awaitable<void>;
    auto read() -> boost::awaitable<json>;

private:
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket;
};
```

Usually, I would go with a callback system that go (very) roughly like this.

```
using command_it_t = std::uint32_t;

// global incrementing command id
command_it_t command_id = 0;

// All callbacks associated with commands
std::unordered_map<command_id_t, std::function<void(json)>> callbacks;

void write_command_to_socket(
    boost::io_context& ioc,
    socket_session& session,
    json command,
    std::function<void(json)> callback
) {
    boost::co_spawn(ioc, session->write(command), asio::detached);
    callbacks.emplace(command_id++, callback);
}

// ... somewhere in the read loop, we call this:
void call_command(json response) {
    if (auto const& command_id = response["command"]; command_id.is_integer()) {
        if (auto const it = callbacks.find(command_id_t{command_id}); it != callbacks.end()) {
            // We found the callback for this command, call it!
            auto const& [id, callback] = *it;
            callback(response["payload"]);
            callbacks.erase(it);
        }
    }
}
```

It would be used like this:

```
write_command_to_socket(ioc, session, json_request, [](json response) {
    // do stuff
});
```

---

As I began using coroutine more and more for asynchronous code, I noticed that it's a golden opportunity to use them in that kind of system.

Instead of sending a callback to the write function, it would return a `boost::awaitable<json>`, that would contain the response payload, I imagined it a bit like this:

```
auto const json_response = co_await write_command_to_socket(session, json_request);
```

#### Okay, here's the problem

So the first step to do that was to transform my code like this:

```
void write_command_to_socket(socket_session& session, json command) {
    co_await session->write(command);
    co_return /* response data from the read loop?? */
}
```

I noticed that I don't have any mean to await on the response, as it is on another async loop. I was able to imagine a system that looked like I wanted, but I have no idea how to translate my own mental model to asio with coroutines.

```
// Type from my mental model: an async promise
template<typename T>
struct promise {
    auto get_value() -> boost::awaitable<T>;
    auto write_value(T value);
};

// Instead of callbacks, my mental model needs promises structured in a similar way:
std::unordered_map<command_id_t, promise<json>> promises;

void write_command_to_socket(socket_session& session, json command) {
    auto const [it, inserted] = promises.emplace(session_id++, promise<json>{});
    auto const [id, promise] = *it;

    co_await session->write(command);

    // Here we awaits until the reader loop sets the value
    auto const response_json = co_await promise.get_value();
    co_return response_json;
}

// ... somewhere in the read loop

void call_command(json response) {
    if (auto const& command_id = response["command"]; command_id.is_integer()) {
        if(auto const it = promises.find(command_id_t{command_id}); it != promises.end()) {
            auto const& [id, promise] = *it;

            // Effectively calls the write_command_to_socket coroutine to continue
            promise.write_value(response["payload"]);
            promise.erase(it);
        }
    }
}
```

As far as I know, the "promise type" I written here as an example don't exist in boost. Without that type, I really struggle how my command system can exist. Would I need to write my own coroutine type for that kind of system? Is there a way I can just get away using boost's coroutine types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With asio, as I said, the "promise type" don't exist. Asio instead uses continuation handlers, which are kind of callbacks that may actually call a callback or resume a coroutine.

To create such continuation handler, one must first initiate an async operation. The async operation can be resumed by another if you want, or composed of many async operation. This is done with the `asio::async_initiate` function, which takes some parameter reguarding the form of the continuation:

```
// the completion token type can be a callback,
// could be `asio::use_awaitable_t const&` or even `asio::detached_t const&`
return asio::async_initiate<CompletionToken, void(json)>(
    [self = shared_from_this()](auto&& handler) {
        // HERE! `handler` is a callable that resumes the coroutine!
        // We can register it somewhere
        callbacks.emplace(command_id, std::forward<decltype(handler)>(handler));
    }
);
```

To resume the async operation, you simply have to call the continuation handler:

```
void call_command(json response) {
    if (auto const& command_id = response["command"]; command_id.is_integer()) {
        if (auto const it = callbacks.find(command_id_t{command_id}); it != callbacks.end()) {
            // We found the continuation handler for this command, call it!
            // It resumes the coroutine with the json as its result
            auto const& [id, callback] = *it;
            callback(response["payload"]);
            callbacks.erase(it);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the rest of the system, how it would look like (very roughtly):

```
using command_it_t = std::uint32_t;

// global incrementing command id
command_it_t command_id = 0;

// All callbacks associated with commands
std::unordered_map<command_id_t, moveable_function<void(json)>> callbacks;

void write_command_to_socket(
    boost::io_context& ioc,
    socket_session session,
    json command
) -> boost::asio::awaitable<json> {
    return asio::async_initiate<boost::asio::use_awaitable_t<> const&, void(json)>(
        [&ioc, session](auto&& handler) {
            callbacks.emplace(command_id, std::forward<decltype(handler)>(handler));
            boost::asio::co_spawn(ioc, session.write(command), asio::detached);
        }
    );
}
```